# How to view the content of a node using nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

```
require 'nokogiri'

f = File.open("test.xml")
doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(f)

description = doc.css('description')

description.each do |item|
    print "#{item}\n"

end
```

Output:

```
<description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty 
      thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
<description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
      centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
<description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
      Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems 
      of being quantum.</description>
<description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in 
      detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
<description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in 
      detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, 
      SAX and more.</description>
<description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
```

How do I prevent nokogiri gem from priting the `<description>` tag pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.content` method as follows:

```
require 'nokogiri'

f = File.open("test.xml")
doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(f)

description = doc.css('description')

description.each do |item|
    print "#{item.content}\n"

end
```